# Angular-JS strict-DI doesn't like injecting resolved results from $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I hit some problems minifying my Angular code so I turned on ng-strict-di

One problem seems to reside in the way I resolve a promise on a route in my app.js config

```
.when('/:userId', {
           templateUrl: 'views/main.html', 
           controller: 'MyCtrl',  
           resolve : {
               myDependency : function(Cache, Model, $route){ 
                  return Cache.getCached( $route.current.params.userId); 
               } 
           }
      })
```

Then I inject this resolved promise into the MyCtrl controller

```
angular.module('myApp') 
    .controller('MyCtrl',[ 'myDependency',  '$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function (myDependency, $scope, $rootScope, $timeout) { 
 etc...
```

However I get an error from Angular

```
[Error] Error: [$injector:strictdi] myDependency is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

The problem appears to be traceable to the resolve definition in app.js because I can change the name of 'myDependency' there in the resolve and the error message uses the name from there rather than the name of the dependency in myCtrl.  And I am explicitly listing the name of the dependency in the myCtrl controller. The app works, but I cannot minify this code because of the problem with this error.

Comment: Mahesh was right (below) but I found my solution was to run the ng-annotate task to remove and re-write the dependencies. ng-strict-di was invaluable in highlighting the problem areas.

Answer (score 7):

Follow strict-di for resolve as well. Hope this works!

```
resolve : {
           myDependency : ['Cache', 'Model', '$route', function(Cache, Model, $route){ 
               return Cache.getCached( $route.current.params.userId); 
           } 
     ]}
```

Comment: I wondered if something like that might work,  but I then get an error that my 'Cache' and 'Model' dependencies (they are my custom ones) are not known as providers. I can't inject them one level up to the config for the same reason.  Thanks for suggesting something as I'm scratching my head on this.

Comment: I added a gulp-ng-annotate task to my build and things are fixed now (I used remove and add to rewrite all my annotations). Strange because the resolve clause has been transformed as you suggested and now it works. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I catched the same problem and @Mahesh Sapkal solution was right.

But if look at this in details then my problem was that `ng-annotate` does not detect correctly that function must be annotated. So I added /*@ngInject*/ comment and it works now!

```
app.config(/*@ngInject*/function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/tables', {
            template: templateList,
            controller: 'TableListController',
            resolve: {
                initial: /*@ngInject*/function (tableListControllerInitial) {
                    return tableListControllerInitial();
                }
            }
        })
```